# Buttons as Outlets vs IBActions [Objective C + Xcode]

Tags: objective-c, xcode, button

**What is the point of ever setting a button as an outlet?** I am following a tutorial and the teacher didn't really mention why he set a button as an outlet. A button is suppose to do an action/call a method and so we set it as an IBAction.

He sets the button as an outlet and then proceeds to change the text of the button through Xcode in viewDidLoad, but why not just keep it as an IBAction and change the text by using setTitle: forState:UIControlStateNormal ?

*Isn't a button suppose to cause an action by definition?*

Comment: How do you plan on changing the text using `setTitle` if you only have the button connected to an action?

Comment: Can I not use setTitle in viewDidLoad?

Comment: Thats true, thank you. Also as I asked below, is there ever a need to have an Outlet & and Action? If so, how would I do this? Just create two connections?

Comment: Ahh, I see your confusion. Yes. You create an outlet to connect your button to your class and then you can also create an action for it. I assume your using Swift so when you drag to create the action, look at the dropdown options to change it to an action.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in some logic cases you would need to change the behaviour of the button , e.g. upon invoking an action (triggered by other event )you will need to disable it or change its backgroundColor or text.

you don't have to set at all times , but in many cases it is really useful

Comment: That makes sense, but then why use a button when we can just use a label? The button doesn't perform an action but instead changes properties based on another event. UNLESS, you are saying that there is a way to make a button into an IBAction AND and IBOutlet?

Comment: yes ofcourse it can be both , actually a UIButton could be connected to multiple IBActions   /n  check this  [link](http://klanguedoc.hubpages.com/hub/IOS-5-A-Beginners-Guide-to-Storyboard-Connection) it is very useful for beginners